Evaluating $\sum_{k=1}^{n}2^k\cdot \tan^{-1}k$
As stated above I need help evaluating $$\sum_{k=1}^{n}2^k\cdot \tan^{-1}k$$
My attempts include:

using $\arctan(x)=\frac{\pi}{2}-\operatorname{arccot}(x)$ and playing with the summa(don't know what to do about the $\cot^{-1}$ )

I thought AGP (arithmetic geometric progression) was needed but failed to find some good relation with $\arctan(x)$

No idea what to telescope here.

evaluating $f'$ where $f(x)=2^x \arctan(x)$. I don't think integrating this will work either.

Then I thought maybe if I find closed form for $2^k \tan^{-1}x$ but I don't think that exists.


I have searched but the questions asked are kind of similar but not useful. I don't know how to implement results like $$\sum_{k=0}^{n} 2^k\cdot \tan(2^k x)=\cot x-2^{n+1}\cot(2^{n+1}x)$$ and
$$\cot(x)-2\cot(2x)=\tan(x)$$ here.
A solution would be highly appreciated.
EDIT as told by @Amrut this is the original question


Are you sure there's no typo? Seems like no nice closed form exists

I thought so too, but the question stated, find $\alpha \pi$ if $\alpha=\frac{S_2-3^x}{S_3}$ where $S_i=\sum_{k=1}^{n}i^k\cdot tan^{-1}k$. My friend suggested this question so I am not sure about the validity though.

How about you add in the original question too, that would be better, $2^k$ shoots up for large $n$

According to how the question is phrased, it looks like the answer might be a constant. In a multiple-choice exam, you should just set n=1.

@AkshajMishra I doubt the exam would have $4+\frac23\pi$ as the answer

@AmrutAyan Just an idea

I think there is a typo on the picture, it should be $3^n$ instead of $3^k$ right?

It can be $3^k$ if it is included in the sum. Then it would be a geometric series.

Have a look at my conjecture

This is too much complicated.
If the problem is to compute
$$S_n=\sum_{k=1}^{n}a^k\, \tan^{-1}(k)$$ I do not think that we could expect any closed form.
However, we can have obtain the result considering the continuous case
$$I=\int a^k\, \tan^{-1}(k)\,dk=\int e^{\alpha k}\, \tan^{-1}(k)\,dk\quad \quad \text{where}\quad \alpha=\log(a)$$ One integration by parts (with $u=\tan^{-1}(k)$) gives
$$I=\frac{e^{\alpha  k}\, \tan ^{-1}(k)}{\alpha }-\frac 1 {\alpha}\int \frac{e^{\alpha  k} } {k^2+1}\,dk$$
$$J=\int \frac{e^{\alpha  k} } {k^2+1}\,dk=\int \frac{e^{\alpha  k} } {(k+i)(k-i)}\,dk=\frac i2\Bigg(\int \frac{e^{\alpha  k}}{k+i}\,dk-\int \frac{e^{\alpha  k}}{k-i}\,dk \Bigg)$$
Obvious changes of variable
$$\int\frac{e^{\alpha  k}}{k+\beta}\,dk=e^{-\alpha  \beta }\,\, \text{Ei}(\alpha  (k+\beta ))$$
Considering
$$T_n=\frac{\int_{1}^n \big(2^k \tan ^{-1}(k)+3^k\big)}{\int_{1}^n 3^k \tan ^{-1}(k)}$$
If $n$ is large
$$T_n\sim \frac 2 \pi + \frac{4 \pi }{31 n}+\frac{2 \pi }{11
   n^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^3}\right)$$
The same result is obtained using the simplest form of Euler-MacLaurin summation. To give an idea of what it would give
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
n & \text{numerator}   & \text{denominator} & \text{ratio}\\
 10^1 & 9.15852\times 10^4 & 1.30274\times 10^5 & 7.03020\times 10^{-1} \\
 10^2 & 7.73066\times 10^{47} & 1.20660\times 10^{48} & 6.40699\times 10^{-1} \\
 10^3 & 1.98311\times 10^{477} & 3.11307\times 10^{477} &
   6.37025\times 10^{-1} \\
 10^4 & 2.44706\times 10^{4771} & 3.84353\times 10^{4771}
   & 6.36660\times 10^{-1} \\
 10^5 & 2.00246\times 10^{47712} & 3.14543\times
   10^{47712} & 6.36624\times 10^{-1} \\
 10^6 & 2.69657\times 10^{477121} & 4.23575\times
   10^{477121} & 6.36620\times 10^{-1} \\
\end{array}
\right)$$
Conjecture
For any $a>1$
$$\large\color{blue}{\underset{n\to \infty }{\text{limit}}\Bigg(S_n(a)=\frac{\sum _{k=1}^{n } \left(a^k \tan^{-1}(k)+(a+1)^k\right)}
{\sum _{k=1}^{n } (a+1)^k \tan ^{-1}(k)}\Bigg)=\frac 2\pi}$$
Computing exactly $S_{10^5}(a)$, the results
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
\large a & S_{10^5}(a) \\
 1 & 0.636623825281258 \\
 2 & 0.636623825260993 \\
 3 & 0.636623825254238 \\
 4 & 0.636623825250861 \\
 5 & 0.636623825248834 \\
 6 & 0.636623825247483 \\
 7 & 0.636623825246518 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$
